# How to create new count column based on adjacent combinations in existing table

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery, combinations

I have a simple table I've already built in BigQuery and all I want to do is what feels like a simple count of the number of times the combination of the **person_id** and the specific activity in the **activity** column has appeared in that table and create as a new column with a value/count of the adjacent combination in every row: '**combination_count'** There are thousands of rows in the table so it's no good creating a filter or wheres etc.

It feels really simple but it's driving me mad. I've tried using counts and partitions but it doesn't work for me.

desired result:

| person_id | activity | combination_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | activity_1 | 1 |
| 1234 | activity_1 | 2 |
| 1234 | activity_2 | 1 |
| 5678 | activity_1 | 1 |

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by person_id, activity order by person_id)
from t;
```